# Jboss cant reconnect to Mysql after database restart

Tags: mysql, jboss7.x, jca

Hello we use JBOSS AS 7.1.1 Final.
Simple JPA Hibernate architecture versus Mysql.

The xa-datasource looks like:

```
<xa-datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/db" pool-name="db" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
<xa-datasource-property name="ServerName">
localhost
</xa-datasource-property>
<xa-datasource-property name="DatabaseName">
db
</xa-datasource-property>
<xa-datasource-property name="User">
root
</xa-datasource-property>
<xa-datasource-property name="Password">
xxxxx
</xa-datasource-property>
<xa-datasource-property name="AutoReconnectForPools">
true
</xa-datasource-property>
<xa-datasource-property name="FailOverReadOnly">
false
</xa-datasource-property>
<xa-datasource-property name="MaxReconnects">
100
</xa-datasource-property>
<xa-datasource-property name="ReconnectAtTxEnd">
true
</xa-datasource-property>
<driver>com.mysql</driver>
<transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</transaction-isolation>
<validation>
<valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
<check-valid-connection-sql>select 1</check-valid-connection-sql>
<exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLExceptionSorter"/>
</validation>
</xa-datasource>
```

After the MySQL is restarted, JBOSS should  renew the connection (reconnect) but it doesnt happen. Please advise

Answer (score 5):

It works for me. Try to add this:

```
<validation>
    <check-valid-connection-sql>select 1</check-valid-connection-sql>
    <background-validation>true</background-validation>
    <background-validation-millis>15000</background-validation-millis>
</validation>
```

Comment: This works for me as well, but do you mind explaining how and why?